# How can i make a funtcion/loop to generete severals data frames

Tags: r, function, loops, r-sf

I have a DF and I need to group_by "Province" summarising by population and creating 1 data frame for each province?
I trying by looping but it doesen work!

```
 shape %>% 
   group_by(provincia) %>% 
   summarise(poblacion = sum(personas)) %>% 
   as.data.frame()
}


thanx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the as.data.frame() before the group_by().  When grouping and summarizing on an sf object it is combining the spatial polygons based on the grouping variable, similar to a dissolve in GIS. If there could be any NA in your data set would want to include na.rm=TRUE when summing

```
 shape %>% 
   as.data.frame() %>%
   group_by(provincia) %>% 
   summarise(poblacion = sum(personas, na.rm=T))
```

If you want to seperate out the result into separate data frames you could use group_split()

```
 shape %>% 
   as.data.frame() %>%
   group_by(provincia) %>% 
   summarise(poblacion = sum(personas, na.rm=T)) %>% 
   group_split(provincia)
```